# Bolzano-Weierstrass on space of sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence of functions is bounded uniformly, then can I say that there is a subsequence of it converging uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no because the unit ball in $C[a,b]$ is not compact.